# how can i stop a function from adding a line break after it adds a readmore extension to a wordpress excerpt in a customized recent posts widget?

Tags: php

hi everyone im trying to add a readmore extension "..." to the end of a wordpress excerpt that has a click able permalink  on the same line as the excerpt inside of the "recent post plus" word press widget

i cant seem to figure out why its placing the read more extension "..." on another line  below the excerpts. you can see a live example of the problem at the bottom of  my test page here

http://blog.bmxboss.com/

its appearing like this on the page

excerpt

...

i would like it to display like this if possible

excerpt...

here is the php code from the widget that i think is controlling it  if i need to post the entire widgets code by request i will for now here are what i think are the primary bits of code being used for this part of the widgets functionality here is the  function generating the excerpt with the extension and its output to the page im new to php so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
// Custom rpwp_excerpt function  

function rpwp_excerpt($count){
$permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
$excerpt = get_the_content();
$excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
$excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, $count);
$excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " "));
$excerpt = $excerpt.'<a href="'.$permalink.'">...</a>';
return $excerpt;
}

//output of the excerpt and title to the page 
            <p>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title_limit( 15, ''); ?></a>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo rpwp_excerpt($instance['characters']);?></a> 
            </p>
```

Comment: view source., your html is wrong, you dont close the previous link

Comment: thanks for pointing that out dagon i fixed the link  but it still seems to be creating a line break any ideas?

Comment: Looking at the site you have two anchor links being created, one for the text and one for `...`. I guess you have an anchor tag inside an anchor tag when you render the excerpt using `rpwp_excerpt`

Answer (score 0):

hi thanks for you input anpsmn. i got it to work by removing the anchor link from within the other anchor link thanks to your insight and replacing it with  '...'  its still a click able  permalink by connecting it directly to the excerpt which is exactly what i needed =)  im just preparing to style it with onhover css and a jsscrollpane scrollbar so i needed to be able to control the length of the title and excerpt with the ability to style the title and excerpt separately here is the new function code below the output to the page remained the same thanks =)

```
//rpwp_excerpt

function rpwp_excerpt($count){
$permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
$excerpt = get_the_content();
$excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
$excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, $count);
$excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " "));
$excerpt = $excerpt.'...';
return $excerpt;
}   

//output to the page
            <p>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title_limit( 15, ''); ?></a>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo rpwp_excerpt($instance['characters']);?></a> 
            </p>
```